# How to compare dropdown previous value with current value using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a drop down and I want to compare its previous and current value. If previous value is same with current value (I mean no change happened) I would make another logic at if statement.

```
 function filter() {
        var id= "ctl00_plchldContent_dropdown1";
        var current;
        var latest;
        var dropdown = document.getElementById(element.id);
        dropdown.onchange('change', function () {
            current = $('#' + id + ' option:selected').val().trim();
        }).change(function () {
            latest = $('#' + id + ' option:selected').val().trim();
        });

       if(current != previous){
           //logic here
         }
    });
```

Although drop down is not null, I am getting Expected when onchange event object error. How can I fix it? 
I am very new for jquery btw. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by saving the previously clicked option in a data-attribute at the select and compare the currently clicked option to it. It's also necessary to have a `click()` event on the options instead of a `change()` event at the select as this would not be called if the selected option is the same option as before.

```js
$("#ctl00_plchldContent_dropdown1 option").on("click", function() {
  let selected = $(this).val();
  if ($(this).parent("select").attr("data-previous") == selected) {
    alert("Same value as previously.")
  }
  $(this).parent("select").attr("data-previous", selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ctl00_plchldContent_dropdown1">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The function is called many times function, if I only click the drop down once. Because of calling more than one, data-previous attributes is set to new selected value.Then, If  statement becomes correct. So, it does not work. I added else clause after if, but  this did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `global` variable to store selected item, after change set `selected` as `newSelected` value

```
var selected = $("#ctl00_plchldContent_dropdown1").val();

$("#ctl00_plchldContent_dropdown1").change(function() {

  let newSelected = $("#ctl00_plchldContent_dropdown1").val();
  if (newSelected != selected) {
    alert("Changed");
    selected = newSelected;
  }
});
```

```js
var selected = $("#ctl00_plchldContent_dropdown1").val();

$("#ctl00_plchldContent_dropdown1").change(function() {
  
  let newSelected = $("#ctl00_plchldContent_dropdown1").val();
  if (newSelected != selected) {
    alert("Changed");
    selected = newSelected;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ctl00_plchldContent_dropdown1">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```